# counting the number of times a word is used

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spread sheet and I'm trying to count the number of times a word is used, but the problem is that, it counts words that have that word inside them

**e.g** I am searching for the word **CPL** and because the word **LCPL** is in the range it also gets counted, how can I count only CPL.

This is my code:

```
 =COUNTIF(F4:F26,"*CPL*")
```

Cheers

Comment: does * means wild card? if yess you need yo remove those.

Comment: Hi, `=COUNTIF(F4:F26,"CPL")` counts number of cells with only `CPL`. `=COUNTIF(F4:F26,"*CPL*")` can be used to get count of cells which contains `CPL` as a part of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the *'s. They are wildcards.

Comment: Cheers easy solution :)